# How do I update a file everytime I execute an addition statement?

Tags: python

Take this code for example:

```
num = 0

print("Hello World.") #just to know it ran
num += 1

fh = open("test.txt", "a")
fh.write(f"{num}\n")
```

It would open up a text file with the number 1 each time you ran it.
But for my case, I want it so it would add 1 each time you ran the program
So if you ran it once, it would append 1, ran it twice, append 2 and so on...

Comment: If you were to run the program on its own over and over, you could open the file in `r` mode instead of `a`, parse the last line of the file, add 1 and write it back to the file everytime you run it. However, I think what you are looking for are loops. Look up `for` and `while` loops and give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure to understand correctly, but what I understand is that you have in input file (that is empty at start), then when you run your script once it contains:

```
1
```

If you run it again:

```
1
2
```

And after *n* times:

```
1
2
3
...
<n>
```

If I get it correctly, then you need to:

1. read the file to find the last value
2. append this value + 1 to the file

Which translates to:

```py
def file_last_line(file_name):
  line = None
  with open(file_name, "r") as f:
    for line in f:
      pass
  return line

def append(file_name, value):
  with open(file_name, "a") as f:
    f.write(f"{str(value)}\n")

def increment(file_name):
  last_line = file_last_line(file_name) or 0
  last_value = int(last_line)
  append(file_name, last_value+1) 

increment("test.txt")
```

If the file is more complex then you'll need to do some more work inside `file_last_line` to extract the last value you wrote. Or in this case, maybe the best solution would even be to store the last value you wrote in another file.

Some explanations on minor details here:

- declaration of `line = None` allows you to save it from destruction at the end of the `for` loop
- `last_line = file_last_line(file_name) or 0` is a shortcut for:

```py
last_line = file_last_line(file_name)
if not last_line:
    last_line = 0
```